# looking for a functional minimizer for use in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I am new to VBA code and am working on doing some nonlinear curve fitting inside of a UDF in excel. I am familiar with Matlab where most of my experience is from. I am looking for a Sub/Function that will give me functionality similar to fminsearch() from Matlab. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Edit(2) in response to Brad

Say I want to write my own UDF that uses a minimization to find the cube root of a number iteratively. Could I write the following function?

```
Function myCubRootSResd(root As Double, rootCubed As Double) As Double 
Dim a As Double 
a = (root * root * root - rootCubed)
myCubRootSResd = a * a
End Function
```

Then this could be used in conjunction with Solver to find the cube root of any number by setting the output of this function to zero by changing the input “root”. However this is just one step that I need to perform in the UDF I am trying to write and this output (in this case the cube root) I need to use inside of my UDF which ultimately calculates the ultimate output. Then I want to use relative referencing to use my overall UDF to calculate over a range of inputs. I believe this would require doing the minimization inside of VBA and not reference cells. The encapsulating function in this case would handle the value of “root” and just return that. It would only have one input which was “rootCubed” and would just pass this along to myCubeRootSResd. So it would look something like this:

```
Function myCubeRootFinder(rootCubed as Double) as Double

……. 

End Function
```

Any help would be very appreciated I have been trying to find a simple solution to this for a while now and I just have not found an example of anyone doing this type of numerical minimization in VBA.

I realize that this may not be the way to go about this in VBA but the functionality needs to be preserved. Thank you for your patients with me.

Comment: I'll come back and see if I can answer this in the context of solver a little later today (when I have a moment), however Matlab's fminsearch function uses the Nelder-Mead method, which is actually quite simple, and could probably be coded by a first-second year university(/college) student. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method

Comment: Even better: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/bsotu2d.html#bsgpq6p-11

Answer (score 2):

OK I had some fun.

Create a class called FuncEval:

```
Option Explicit

Dim output_ As Double
Dim input_() As Double

Public Property Get VectArr() As Double()
    VectArr = input_
End Property

Public Function Vect(i As Integer)
    Vect = input_(i)
End Function

Public Sub SetVect(ByRef newVect() As Double)
    Dim i As Integer
    ReDim input_(LBound(newVect) To UBound(newVect)) As Double
    For i = LBound(newVect) To UBound(newVect)
        input_(i) = newVect(i)
    Next i
End Sub

Public Property Get Result() As Double
    Result = output_
End Property

Public Property Let Result(newRes As Double)
    output_ = newRes
End Property
```

And a class called Func:

```
Option Explicit

Private cube_ As Double

Public Property Let Cube(newCube As Double)
    cube_ = newCube
End Property

Public Function Eval(ByRef val() As Double) As FuncEval
    Dim ret As New FuncEval
    ret.Result = Abs(cube_ - val(0) * val(0) * val(0))
    ret.SetVect val
    Set Eval = ret
End Function
```

Now put this code in a standard module:

```
Option Explicit

Function NelderMead(f As Func, _
                    ByRef guess() As Double) As Double()

    'Algorithm follows that outlined here:
    'http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/bsotu2d.html#bsgpq6p-11

    'Used as the perturbation for the initial guess when guess(i) == 0
    Dim zeroPert As Double
    zeroPert = 0.00025
    'The factor each element of guess(i) is multiplied by to obtain the
    'initial simplex
    Dim pertFact As Double
    pertFact = 1.05
    'Tolerance
    Dim eps As Double
    eps = 0.000000000001

    Dim shrink As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim simplex() As Variant
    Dim origVal As Double, lowest As Double
    Dim m() As Double, r() As Double, s() As Double, c() As Double, cc() As Double, diff() As Double
    Dim FE As FuncEval, FR As FuncEval, FS As FuncEval, FC As FuncEval, FCC As FuncEval, newFE As FuncEval

    n = UBound(guess) - LBound(guess) + 1
    ReDim m(LBound(guess) To UBound(guess)) As Double
    ReDim r(LBound(guess) To UBound(guess)) As Double
    ReDim s(LBound(guess) To UBound(guess)) As Double
    ReDim c(LBound(guess) To UBound(guess)) As Double
    ReDim cc(LBound(guess) To UBound(guess)) As Double
    ReDim diff(LBound(guess) To UBound(guess)) As Double
    ReDim simplex(LBound(guess) To UBound(guess) + 1) As Variant

    Set simplex(LBound(simplex)) = f.Eval(guess)

    'Generate the simplex
    For i = LBound(guess) To UBound(guess)
        origVal = guess(i)
        If origVal = 0 Then
            guess(i) = zeroPert
        Else
            guess(i) = pertFact * origVal
        End If
        Set simplex(LBound(simplex) + i - LBound(guess) + 1) = f.Eval(guess)
        guess(i) = origVal
    Next i

    'Sort the simplex by f(x)
    For i = LBound(simplex) To UBound(simplex) - 1
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(simplex)
            If simplex(i).Result > simplex(j).Result Then
                Set FE = simplex(i)
                Set simplex(i) = simplex(j)
                Set simplex(j) = FE
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Do

        Set newFE = Nothing
        shrink = False
        lowest = simplex(LBound(simplex)).Result

        'Calculate m
        For i = LBound(m) To UBound(m)
            m(i) = 0
            For j = LBound(simplex) To UBound(simplex) - 1
                m(i) = m(i) + simplex(j).Vect(i)
            Next j
            m(i) = m(i) / n
        Next i

        'Calculate the reflected point
        For i = LBound(r) To UBound(r)
            r(i) = 2 * m(i) - simplex(UBound(simplex)).Vect(i)
        Next i
        Set FR = f.Eval(r)

        'Check acceptance conditions
        If (simplex(LBound(simplex)).Result <= FR.Result) And (FR.Result < simplex(UBound(simplex) - 1).Result) Then
            'Accept r, replace the worst value and iterate
            Set newFE = FR
        ElseIf FR.Result < simplex(LBound(simplex)).Result Then
            'Calculate the expansion point, s
            For i = LBound(s) To UBound(s)
                s(i) = m(i) + 2 * (m(i) - simplex(UBound(simplex)).Vect(i))
            Next i
            Set FS = f.Eval(s)
            If FS.Result < FR.Result Then
                Set newFE = FS
            Else
                Set newFE = FR
            End If
        ElseIf FR.Result >= simplex(UBound(simplex) - 1).Result Then
            'Perform a contraction between m and the better of x(n+1) and r
            If FR.Result < simplex(UBound(simplex)).Result Then
                'Contract outside
                For i = LBound(c) To UBound(c)
                    c(i) = m(i) + (r(i) - m(i)) / 2
                Next i
                Set FC = f.Eval(c)
                If FC.Result < FR.Result Then
                    Set newFE = FC
                Else
                    shrink = True
                End If
            Else
                'Contract inside
                For i = LBound(cc) To UBound(cc)
                    cc(i) = m(i) + (simplex(UBound(simplex)).Vect(i) - m(i)) / 2
                Next i
                Set FCC = f.Eval(cc)
                If FCC.Result < simplex(UBound(simplex)).Result Then
                    Set newFE = FCC
                Else
                    shrink = True
                End If
            End If
        End If

        'Shrink if required
        If shrink Then
            For i = LBound(simplex) + 1 To UBound(simplex)
                For j = LBound(simplex(i).VectArr) To UBound(simplex(i).VectArr)
                    diff(j) = simplex(LBound(simplex)).Vect(j) + (simplex(i).Vect(j) - simplex(LBound(simplex)).Vect(j)) / 2
                Next j
                Set simplex(i) = f.Eval(diff)
            Next i
        End If

        'Insert the new element in place
        If Not newFE Is Nothing Then
            For i = LBound(simplex) To UBound(simplex)
                If simplex(i).Result > newFE.Result Then
                    For j = UBound(simplex) To i + 1 Step -1
                        Set simplex(j) = simplex(j - 1)
                    Next j
                    Set simplex(i) = newFE
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
        End If

    Loop Until (simplex(UBound(simplex)).Result - simplex(LBound(simplex)).Result) < eps

    NelderMead = simplex(LBound(simplex)).VectArr

End Function

Function test(cube, guess) As Double

    Dim f As New Func
    Dim guessVec(0 To 0) As Double
    Dim Result() As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim output As String

    f.cube = cube
    guessVec(0) = guess

    Result = NelderMead(f, guessVec)

    test = Result(0)

End Function
```

The Func class contains your residual function. The NelderMead method only requires the Result method of the Func class, so you can do as you wish with the Func class so long as the Eval method handles a vector of the same length as your initial guess and returns a FuncEval object.

Call the test function to see it in action. Note, I haven't actually tested with multi-dimensional vectors, I have to go out, let me know if you have any problems!

**Edit: suggestion for generalising function passing**

You'll need to make a number of different classes for different problems. Which means to keep the NelderMead function general, you'll need to change it's declaration line to the following:

```
Function NelderMead(f As Object, _
                    ByRef guess() As Double) As Double()
```

Whatever f is, it must always have an Eval method which takes an array of doubles.

**Edit: function passing, probably the (silly) way it's meant to be done in VBA**

```
Function f(x() As Double) As Double
    f = x(0) * x(0)
End Function

Sub Test()
    Dim x(0 To 0) As Double
    x(0) = 5
    Debug.Print Application.Run("f", x)
End Sub
```

Using this method you'd have the following declaration:

```
Function NelderMead(f As String, _
                    ByRef guess() As Double) As Double()
```

Then call f using the Application.Run syntax above. You'd need to make a couple of changes inside the function too. It's not pretty, but frankly it wasn't that pretty to begin with.

Comment: Note that I didn't focus too heavily on efficiency (who would I be kidding, it's VBA, not Haskell) or convergence conditions. I'd recommend you review at least the latter.

Comment: Wow this is great! I was able to reduce the pertFact and have not had any convergence issues yet. I had considered writing my own minimizer but I'm not sure that I could have tackled this problem in VBA. I guess now I just need to make Func an interface so that I can make manny different functions to minimize? I have learned alot from reading through this code on how VBA works. Thank you for all the help

Comment: Glad you like it :). Unfortunately you'll need to make a new func object (not just an instance, an entirely new class) for every function you want to minimise. The reason for this is that unless you want to parse a function string, I can't think of any way to pass functions around in VBA. There may be some alternative using the VBIDE library- or you could post another question in here about it- in fact, I think I might do just that, out of interest.

Comment: Which means you'll need to make a change to the code. I've edited my answer to show what.

Comment: Reducing pertfact just means your initial "guess window" is smaller. If you want a more accurate answer you need to reduce eps. Note though that there might be convergence issues and numerical error if you reduce it too far. Often 10^-12 is a pretty reasonable value.

Comment: Is it neceessary to create new class ? edit: did not see the date of the posts....

Comment: I don't remember this very well and have no way to test changes at the moment, so I might not be very helpful. However, re-reading my answer, it looks as though you should be able to make changes to the original code as specified in the last edit (and probably a couple of cascading edits as required to make the code compile) then define a function, e.g. 'f' as declared in the edit, and call NelderMead on the function to be minimised as follows: NelderMead("f", guessVec). Similarly, define a function "g" and call NelderMead("g", guessVec). Though it might be easier to just make new classes..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Solver add-in that comes with Excel to solve a minimise problem.

Comment: I thought that initially also but I think you cannot change any cells other than the cell that the formula resides in from a UDF. Solver will work if you want to just perform the calculation once on a spread sheet but I need to so this inside VBA so that this can be enclosed inside my UDF. I may be mistaken but is there a way to use solver without a cell reference?

Comment: I believe you can use the Solver in a UDF. Try this link http://peltiertech.com/Excel/SolverVBA.html

Comment: I have looked at this maybe I am not seeing how this could be used. I will try to give a simplified example of a problem that shares attributes with my more complex and confusing one.